# Android moveTaskToFront Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-launcher, android-homebutton

Android 4.0 which is now allow the developer to disable the application.

Then I developed a service to bring to application to foreground when the user click the home button.

Now I can bring the application to foreground successful.

But each time I opened the application and then click home button.
it will show the launcher and delay 5-6 second to bring to application to foreground.

I find that the service retried a few time to bring the application to foreground.
But when I click the button on the launcher, it will bring the application to foreground immediately.

Any solution to fix the delay problem?
Thanks.

Comment: are you getting any error/exception in the service?

Comment: no any error/exception
Thanks

Comment: You are saying that the service is retrying. can you share some logs?

Comment: Please share the code from your service..

Comment: Its look like that you want your application to act like home screen.. so why don't you make one of your activity handle the home screen intent.

Comment: i just want to disable the home button . but 4.0 is not allow to do

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To edit a question, please click the "edit" link below the question, rather than paste code into comments. "i just want to disable the home button . but 4.0 is not allow to do" -- create a home screen app.

Comment: As @CommonsWare said you should not try to disable the home button.. this would be bad user experience and your application would be considered spam application..

Comment: the application is in house application.